# Unexpected result for evaluation of logical or in POSIX sh conditional

Tags: shell, posix

Suppose we have an if statement as follows:

```
if [ $(false) ]; then
    echo "?"
fi
```

Then "?" is not printed (the condition is false). However, in the following case, "?!" is printed, why?

```
if [ $(false) -o $(false) ]; then
    echo "?!"
fi
```

Comment: Note that `[` is not a [POSIX `sh`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/sh.html) operator, it's a separate utility aka [`test`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/test.html), here used in the `if` part of a `if/then/elif/else/fi` statement in the `sh` language syntax.

Comment: By the way, Shellcheck points out issues, e.g. by raising SC2046 ("Quote this to prevent word splitting"). This might raise alarm bells if you thought that `$(false)` was going to give you its exit code, because why would word splitting happen on an exit code?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`$(false)` doesn’t evaluate to false, it produces an empty string. Because it isn’t quoted,

```
if [ $(false) ]; then
```

evaluates to

```
if [ ]; then
```

which is false, because `[` with an empty expression is false.

```
if [ $(false) -o $(false) ]; then
```

evaluates to

```
if [ -o ]; then
```

This *doesn’t* use the `-o` operator, it evaluates `-o` as an expression with a single string; `[` with such an expression is true, so the `then` part of the `if` statement runs.

See [the POSIX specification for `test`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html), in particular:

> The algorithm for determining the precedence of the operators and the return value that shall be generated is based on the number of arguments presented to test. (However, when using the "[...]" form, the <right-square-bracket> final argument shall not be counted in this algorithm.)
>
> In the following list, $1, $2, $3, and $4 represent the arguments presented to test:
>
> 0 arguments:
> Exit false (1).
> 1 argument:
> Exit true (0) if $1 is not null; otherwise, exit false.

`test` only considers operators if it is given at least two arguments.

If you want to use a command’s exit status as a condition, don’t put it either in a command substitution or in `[ ]`:

```
if false; then
```

and

```
if false || false; then
```

Note too that [`test`’s `-a` and `-o` operators are deprecated and unreliable](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128_16); you should use the shell’s `&&` and `||` operators instead, *e.g.*

```
if [ "$a" = b ] || [ "$a" = c ]; then
```

Comment: Possibly of note, this exact type of issue is a major part of _why_ the `-o` and `-a` options for `test` and `[` are deprecated and their use is heavily discouraged by sane developers. There are technically other cases as well where they cause problems, but the specific case of one or both sides evaluating to an empty string unexpectedly and changing how the argument list is parsed is probably the biggest issue with their usage.

Comment: Note also that this only happens because the command substitution is unquoted. If quoted, it would evaluate to `""` (i.e. an empty string, which is passed as a separate argument), but when unquoted it gets split+globbed, causing it to evaluate to nothing at all (i.e. no separate argument). As a result, `[ "$(false)" -o "$(false)" ]` evaluates to false (empty string or empty string).

Answer (score 11):

I won't repeat the points made in the fine answers [by @StephenKitt](/a/726262) and [@ilkkachu](/a/726263) here, just focus on what it means to write `if [ $(cmd) ]; then...`.

First note that `[` is not a [POSIX `sh`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/sh.html) operator, it's a separate utility also known as [`test`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/test.html), here used in the `if` part of a `if`/`then`/`elif`/`else`/`fi` statement in the syntax of the [`sh` language](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html).

Its job is to evaluate its arguments as a conditional expression. For instance, if it receives `[`, `a`, `=`, `b` and `]` as arguments or `test`, `a`, `=` and `b`, it will return a false/failure exit status as it has interpreted it as the *"is 'a' the same string as 'b'?"* conditional expression.

`[` is often used as the one and only command in the `if` part of a `if`/`then`/`elif`/`else`/`fi` statement or in `while`/`do`/`done` or `until`/`do`/`done` statement, but it doesn't have to be nor do those statement have to invoke `[` nor a single command.

Doing `[ $(cmd) ]` means calling the `[` command with `[`, the result of the `$(cmd)` expansion and `]` as separate arguments. Then `[` interprets those arguments as a conditional expression and returns true or false depending on the result (also false if it can't understand the expression).

In POSIX sh, `$(cmd)` expands to the standard output of `cmd` stripped of all trailing newline characters, and as it's not quoted and in list context, subject to IFS-splitting, and then globbing (with the behaviour unspecified if there are NUL characters in that output).

So `if [ $(cmd) ]` or `test $(cmd)` doesn't really make any sense.

It's something like asking the question: *"does the output of `cmd`, once split+globbed make up a valid conditional expression that results to true?"*

For instance, if `cmd` outputs `a,*` and  `$IFS` happens to contain `,` and the current working directory contains two files, one called `=`, one called `b`, `[ $(cmd) ]` will call `[` with `[`, `a`, `=`, `b`, `]` as arguments. Quite luckily, that happens to be a valid conditional expression, but one that returns false as `a` is not `b`.

```
$ cd "$(mktemp -d)"
$ touch = b
$ cmd() { echo 'a,*'; }
$ IFS=,
$ set -o xtrace
$ if [ $(cmd) ]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
++ cmd
++ echo 'a,*'
+ '[' a = b ']'
+ echo no
no
```

Now, `[ "$(cmd)" ]` makes quite a bit more sense. Quoting a command substitution doesn't prevent the stripping of trailing newline characters, still is unspecified when `cmd` outputs NULs, but it prevents split+glob and empty removal. So `[` will always be passed 3 arguments: `[`, the output of `cmd` stripped of trailing newline characters and `]`. With one argument beside `[` and `]`, `[` returns true if and only if that argument is not an empty string, it's the same as `[ -n "$(cmd)" ]`.

So it's like saying: *"does `cmd` output at least one character that is not a newline character (or NUL)"*. For commands that output text (text being guaranteed to be made of lines and to not contain NULs), that's *"does `cmd` output at least one non-empty line?"*

Except for short output, it does that in an inefficient way, as we end up reading the whole output and storing it in memory, and then pass is to `[`.

```
if cmd | grep -q .; then...
```

Would have been more efficient as `grep` would exit with *true* as soon as it finds a line that contains at least one character.

If `cmd` was `yes`, `if [ "$(cmd)" ]` would eventually crash the shell with a *not enough memory* error, while `if cmd | grep -q .` would output yes straight away (and `yes` would be terminated via a SIGPIPE signal).

To test whether `cmd` succeeds regardless of what it may or may not output, you just do:

```
if cmd; then
  echo cmd succeeded
else
  echo cmd failed
fi
```

`if $(cmd); then` is another example of code that makes little sense. But there's a bit of a twist in the example of `cmd` being `false`.

Again, `$(cmd)` is stripped of the trailing newline characters, subject to split+glob. But this time, the resulting words are not passed to a `[` / `test` utility, but the first of those words if any is treated as the command to execute, and all the words passed as arguments to it.

So if `cmd` outputs `echo:hello:world` and `$IFS` contains `:`, that ends up running `echo` with `echo`, `hello` and `world` as arguments and assuming `echo` manages to successfully write `"hello world\n"` on its stdout, it will return true/success, so the `then` part will be run.

Now, if `cmd` produces no output or only newline characters and IFS-whitespace characters, then `$(cmd)` will result in no word at all, so another command won't be run, and then at that point, it's the exit status of `cmd` itself that will matter to the `if` statement.

In:

```
if $(false); then
  echo yes
else
  echo no
fi
```

`no` is output because since `false` produces no output, no command was run and it's the exit status of `false` that decides that the `else` part be run.

In:

```
if $(echo true; false); then
  echo yes
else
  echo no
fi
```

and assuming `$IFS` contains no `t`, `r`, `u` nor `e` character; `true` ends up being run and it's its exit status that determines the branching in the `if` statement.