# How does -a and -o work in Expressions?

Tags: bash

I'm using the man page for "test".  I understood everything except for the following 2 lines.  Can someone give me an example of how to actually use this because thus far I've been using 1 dimensional tests (i.e. is x = y kind of thing in my tests), so comparing expressions doesn't make too much sense in my head.  I think if someone can show me an example or use case I'd get it.

```
   EXPRESSION1 -a EXPRESSION2
          both EXPRESSION1 and EXPRESSION2 are true

   EXPRESSION1 -o EXPRESSION2
          either EXPRESSION1 or EXPRESSION2 is true
```

Comment: You tagged `bash` and used the phrase "man page for `test`", so *maybe* you are not aware of the following: `test` is a builtin in Bash and `help test` in Bash describes it, but `man test` describes a standalone executable. The builtin and the executable may differ in what they support. Depending on what syntax you use and where (`test`, `/usr/bin/test`, `find … -exec test …`, `sudo test …`, …), you use one or the other. I don't think the answer to your question depends on what `test` you use, but in general it's good to know `man test` does not describe the builtin.

Answer (score 5):

`-a` and `-o` join two expressions, *i.e.* complete expressions which could be used independently with `test`. Thus

```
test "$x" = foo -o "$x" = bar
```

succeeds if

```
test "$x" = foo
```

or

```
test "$x" = bar
```

would succeed, *i.e.* `"$x"` is either `foo` or `bar`.

This can be ambiguous, so [`-a` and `-o` are deprecated](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128_16), and the shell’s operators should be used instead:

```
test "$x" = foo || test "$x" = bar
```

More commonly, this would be written

```
[ "$x" = foo ] || [ "$x" = bar ]
```

See [Unexpected result for evaluation of logical or in POSIX sh conditional](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/726261/86440) for an example of `-o` being used in a confusing manner.

Comment: So if I look at the last line, i still find this confusing.  The last line reads: "is x equal to foo, if this is not true, then is x equal to bar?" .  So, if I assume x=abc, then another way to read the last line is "x is not foo, and it's also not bar".  Thus the overall result is false, Is this correct?

Comment: If `x` is `abc`, then yes, the overall result is false. “`x` is not `foo`, and it’s also not `bar`” isn’t equivalent, it’s the negation (see De Morgan’s laws).